# How To Share Authentication Context between C# OpenIdConnectAuthenticationExtensions Library and Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

We have a C# webforms website where I am prompting the user for Azure AD authentication. I do so with the following code:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = clientId,
    Authority = authority, //aadInstance + tenant - basically a URL
    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
    //TokenValidationParameters and Notifications are also defined below...
}
```

We can retrieve the token from the API once the user logs in via the following code:

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies")
    .GetAwaiter().GetResult().Properties.Dictionary["id_token"];
```

If we use the "id_token" in a [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) call as a "Authentication" header we get the following error:

> Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.

We understand that this doesn't work because of the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62514531/access-token-validation-failure-invalid-audience).

### Question

What changes can we make to me invocation of the UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication library that will allow me to obtain some form of authentication code/token/id that we can then reuse in to access Microsoft Graph API with the permission context of the logged in user?

We are looking for solution in C# that would allow us to generate from a logged in user session some form of usable authentication which could be passed to the Microsoft graph API.

### Research

The [linked post](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Cross_Frame_Scripting) suggests that we [go down the following path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77112747/calling-graph-api-for-teams-after-user-has-logged-in-with-azure-ad-authenticatio), attempting to change the responseType of and scope of the [declaration so that we are returning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?tabs=http) a "access_Token"(OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdTokenToken and GetResult().Properties.Dictionary["access_token"]) along with a token. Using the code we can use a Token API to generate a token that then can be used as an [authentication header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#access-tokens) in the Microsoft Graph API. This didn't work because when we set that it kept on redirecting to the login page with the following error:

> AADSTS70005: The application requested an unsupported response type '' when requesting a token.

We also attempted to use OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken, this worked within our website but the access token that was generated return the same error when we passed it to the Microsoft Graph API(Invalid audience)

We added properties "SaveToken" and "RedeemCode" set to True and we also added resource set to client_id to our OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions, this was necessary to get the website working but it didn't change the error returned by the Microsoft Graph API

We've explored using the Microsoft Graph API method for authentication (https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/token using client secret, token, etc..) This works fine but it's not in the right user context and is not really a implementation of a shared user context.

We've edited Azure permission and added delegate permissions and ensured that in our app registration we returning both a access token and token id, didn't seem to help.

Comment: Firstly, you need to use `OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code`. Secondly, a scope of `OpenIdProfile` gives you no access to any user data. What do you want access to? You need to include that in the scope value and then get a token again e.g. `mail.read`. Set new scopes and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the "id_token" obtained from the OpenIdConnectAuthentication middleware is not the appropriate token to use to access the Microsoft Graph API. Its just used to identify the user and not to get resources from an API. Read further here about these tokens and their uses. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/security-tokens

Instead, you should use the "access_token" obtained from the middleware. You can modify the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions to request the necessary scope for the Microsoft Graph API by adding the appropriate value to the Scope property. For example:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()

{
    ClientId = clientId,
    Authority = authority,
    Scope = "openid profile offline_access User.Read Mail.Read", // Add the necessary scope for Microsoft Graph API
    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
    // ...
}
```

Note that in your case above you need the permissions listed under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http as that is the endpoint you are calling

Then, you can retrieve the "access_token" by calling:

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token")
```

You can then use this "access_token" as the "Authorization" header when making requests to the Microsoft Graph API.

You can find more information about using the Microsoft Graph API SDK in C# on this GitHub repository: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet